# How to create a uzn file for tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I need to build an OCR application that scans passports and so I have chosen tesseract for start. From what I have read there should be a .uzn file that I define, but I can't find any documentation on it. How can I create such a template for tesseract to use.

Answer (score 2):

you can rather use uzn file or let tesseract do the segmentation itself.
anyway checkout the folowing link if you need more informations about uzn file format :
https://github.com/OpenGreekAndLatin/greek-dev/wiki/uzn-format